# Grouping date-level data by month to produce averages in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I return a monthly average with below cells without manually selecting each month separately?

```
  A           B
1 2013-02-13  25600
2 2013-02-14   5000
3 2013-03-15  12300
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pivot tables are the obvious answer. Give your columns titles (Date, Value) in the top row, then create a pivot table.

Add Date as your `row labels`, then right-click any date and group by month.

Then add your Value column to the `values` section of your pivot table. Right-click any value and choose `summarise values by > average`.

Job done!

Comment: The trick of "right-click any date and group by month" is priceless. What I learnt also is you can group by both YEAR and MONTH by holding CTRL key :)